# Azure CDN file download statistics

Tags: azure, microsoft-cdn

How do I *see* file download statistics with Azure CDN and/or get statistics using a .NET program? I want to put a file in Azure CDN and see how many times the file was downloaded, more details like country of downloaders etc would be nice too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is currently such statistics available. All you can see is the number CDN transactions and CDN bandwidth consumed. You can see this in the monthly bill (in billing history).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "manage cdn" button on the portal and it leads you to another portal where you can see analytics. Programmatical access is not supported yet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is for top 250 or top 10 some chart how to have the full report?