# Detailed access logs in Azure CDN

Tags: azure-cdn

Amazon and Google both provide detailed access logs for HTTP requests served by their CDN platforms. As far as I can see there is no such thing in any of Microsoft's CDN solutions (Microsoft, Akamai, Verizon Standard/Premium). There are [diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-azure-diagnostic-logs) and [reports for top resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-advanced-http-reports), but I need the individual requests or at least the total number of requests per URL and day.

I have read [Azure CDN file download statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031109/azure-cdn-file-download-statistics), but it is very old, so something may have changed.

Is it possible to get the access logs we need from a CDN in Azure using a method I have missed, or is this still a dead end?

Comment: I am also looking for this. I subscribe for Diagnostic logs but there is only the total per D,H, M  not which resource, the top 250 excel report is not option for me :-(   Please share if you find solution

Comment: Will do but so far we haven't found anything. I don't think Azure has it. We went for Amazon instead and this was the make or break feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done now, at least if using "Azure CDN from Microsoft". You need to [create a Log Analytics workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace) (if you don't have one already), go to Diagnostics settings on your CDN profile (not endpoint) and [route the raw logs to that workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/enable-raw-logs).

You can also put it in storage, or feed it into an event hub, but I found making reports easiest via log analytics - you can easily create a chart of hit/miss ratio per CDN Point-of-Presence with this:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "AzureCdnAccessLog"
| summarize request_count = count(), totalResponseBytes = sum(toint(responseBytes_s)) by pop_s, cacheStatus_s, sentToOriginShield_b
| order by request_count desc
```

Read the whole of that second link - you may need to re-save endpoints not created recently.

Here's that query used to diagnose that misses from Cape Town (and Johannesburg) were being sent to an origin shield PoP in London before actually being pulled from the origin by the London PoP.

[image: Query and resulting table showing hit/miss per-POP from the last hour]

[image: Chart of hit/miss per-POP]

Comment: Cool, I see that the feature was added in February 2020. Nice to know though it came a bit late for us.